# Visual Studio 2017 FTP Publish - upload only changed files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

When i publish my Asp.Net site to my webhost using FTP publish in VS2017 it copies all the files in the solution; is there anyway to set it so it only uploads the changed files / binaries?

Each time i make (even a small) change it uploads everything again.

Answer (score 1):

update only bin folder and changes files only ....
in publish folder sort by Date Modified option u can easily find change files

Comment: copy bin folder and pest in ftp server

Comment: OK so don't use the VS deploy, but manually copy using FTP client like Filezilla the bin folder?

Comment: ex: if your use MVC and only one view page in change then only copy this view page and pest in FTP server